# 3 different ways to express $S(x)=(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n)^2$

Tags: calculus

Let the function $S(x)$ be a sum, such that $S(x)=(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n)^2$ and $|x|<1$. Which of the following is true: (can be multiple options)

1. $S(x)$ can be expressed as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{2n}$
2. $S(x)$ can be expressed as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^n$
3. $S(x)$ can be expressed as $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$

(1)This one seems to be applying the square to the sum. I think this is one of the properties of these series, so I think it is true.

(2)This one can be rewritten as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nx^n+x^n$, and the square is gone too, after some testing, I declare this one to be true with values $S(0.5)$

(3)This one seems sus, I have no idea how this one is derived, and intuitively it seems false. It's not even a sum and expressed as a fraction as well, which is vastly different from the rest

Comment: Its quite easy to evaluate the given $S(x)$(GP). Now check which options give the same result. For 1) its a GP again. For 2) try differentiating the sum $x^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint 1: $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2\neq a^2+b^2.$

Hint 2: See hint 3. Then perform Taylor series expansion.

Hint 3: Geometric series!!!

Comment: Wait so all 3 are true?

Comment: @ATMOS-atms No. Only two are correct. I would revisit Hint 1. For part 1).  Also, 2) is the same as $\frac{d}{dx}x S(x)$. Once you lookup geometric series you can evaluate the series $S$, which should make things clearer as well.